# C++ Storing File in Binary Tree

Tags: c++, string, binary-tree

I am finishing a C++ project in which I read a text file as a string and store it in a binary tree.  I have to store each letter from the file in a binary tree along with a number of how many times that letter occurs.  I then have to store 2 letter occurrences and so on to k occurrences given by the user.  For example if a file contains abcdef I have to store a, b, c, d, e, f in the tree and then I go through the string again and store ab, bc, cd, de, ef, and abc, bcd, cde, def, etc. up to the number entered by the user.  These are stored with a number of how many times they occur, and if a string is ever passed to the tree and the tree already contains that string, the number of that string is simply incremented by one.  My code is working for single and double occurrences, but for occurrences greater than 2 it is always passing the last double occurrence to the tree twice.

Here is the main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include "binarytree.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string filename;
    string filedata;
    string a;
    string b;
    int num;
    BinaryTree tree;
    fstream file;

    cout << "Please enter a filename: ";
    cin >> filename;

    file.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in);

    if (!file)
    {
    cout << "ERROR: Cannot open file.";
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter the maximum number of consecutive letters to count the occurrences of: ";
        cin >> num;

        while (num < 1)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a number greater than 0: ";
            cin >> num;
        }
    }

    while (getline(file, a))
    {
        filedata += a;
    }

    cout << "File data: " << filedata << endl;
    filedata.erase(remove(filedata.begin(),filedata.end(),' '),filedata.end());
    cout << "File data: " << filedata << endl;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < filedata.size(); i++)
    {
        if (filedata[i] != ' ')
        {
            string a(1, filedata[i]);
            tree.insertNode(a);
        }
    }

    if (num > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < num + 1; i++)
        {
            int k = 1;
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < filedata.size()-1; j++)
            {
                if (filedata[j+k] == '\0')
                    cout << "null" << endl;
                else if (filedata[j+k] != '\0')
                {
                    b = "";
                    b += filedata.substr(j, i);
                    tree.insertNode(b);
                }
            }
            k++;
        }
    }

    file.close();

    tree.displayInOrder();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the binarytree.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "binarytree.h"
using namespace std;

void BinaryTree::insert(TreeNode *&nodePtr, TreeNode *&newNode, string letter)
{

    if (nodePtr == NULL)
    {
        TreeNode *newTreeNode = new TreeNode;
        newTreeNode->letter = letter;
        newTreeNode->value = 1;
        newTreeNode->left = newTreeNode->right = NULL;
        if(newNode->letter > newTreeNode->letter)
            newNode->left = newTreeNode;
        else
            newNode->right = newTreeNode;
    }
    else if (nodePtr->letter > letter)
        insert(nodePtr->left, nodePtr, letter);
    else if (nodePtr->letter < letter)
        insert(nodePtr->right, nodePtr, letter);
    else if (nodePtr->letter == letter)
        nodePtr->value += 1;
}

void BinaryTree::insertNode(string letter)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = new TreeNode;
        root->letter = letter;
        root->value = 1;
        root->left = root->right = NULL;
    }
    else if(root->letter > letter)
        insert(root->left, root, letter);
    else if(root->letter < letter)
        insert(root->right, root, letter);
    else if(root->letter == letter)
        root->value += 1;
}

void BinaryTree::destroySubTree(TreeNode *nodePtr)
{
    if (nodePtr)
    {
        if (nodePtr->left)
            destroySubTree(nodePtr->left);
        if (nodePtr->right)
            destroySubTree(nodePtr->right);
        delete nodePtr;
    }
}

void BinaryTree::displayInOrder(TreeNode *nodePtr) const
{
    if (nodePtr)
    {
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->left);
        cout << nodePtr->letter << ": " << nodePtr->value << endl;
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->right);
    }
}
```

Here is the binarytree.h file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#ifndef BINARYTREE_H_
#define BINARYTREE_H_
using namespace std;

class BinaryTree
{
    private:
        struct TreeNode
        {
            string letter;
            int value;
            TreeNode *left;
            TreeNode *right;
        };

        TreeNode *root;

        void insert(TreeNode *&, TreeNode *&, string);
        void destroySubTree(TreeNode *);
        void deleteNode(int, TreeNode *&);
        void makeDeletion(TreeNode *&);
        void displayInOrder(TreeNode *) const;

    public:
        BinaryTree()
        {
            root = NULL;
        }
        ~BinaryTree()
        {
            destroySubTree(root);
        }
        void insertNode(string);
        void remove(int);
        void displayInOrder() const
        {
            displayInOrder(root);
        }
};

#endif
```

And here is the text file:

```
j a z uu e uu a
```

When the text file is entered in the program along with num 3 for the number of occurrences, this is displayed to the screen:

a: 2
az: 1
azu: 1
e: 1
eu: 1
euu: 1
j: 1
ja: 1
jaz: 1
u: 4
ua: 2
ue: 1
ueu: 1
uu: 2
uua: 1
uue: 1
z: 1
zu: 1
zuu: 1 //(each on a new line)

and as you can see ua is being counted twice when it should only be counted once.  This only occurs when num > 2.  The problem is somewhere in the if(num > 1) statement.  I am trying to avoid the null character being passed to the tree and I added a cout statement to display "null" if null is ever reached but this is never displayed, and I am not sure what is causing the problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you used the debugger, which statement is causing the issue?  What are the values of the variables associated with the statement?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `std::map<char, unsigned int>` or an array of integers?

Comment: The `std::string` type may be overkill for a single letter (character).

Comment: The issue is somewhere in the for loop within the "if (num > 1)" statement, I am using the integer k as a way to change the length of the string that is passed to the tree so that depending on what num is, the string length will be different.

Comment: Decide, are you storing strings or characters into the tree?  You really don't need to worry about the number of characters in a word.  Read a character from the file.  If it is a letter, search the tree.  Insert into tree if not exist, else increment the counter.

Comment: Yes that works for individual letters, but I have to insert strings to the tree for the various recurrences.  For example if my file contains abcd I have to pass each letter and then go back and pass ab, bc, cd, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this loop: `for (unsigned int j = 0; j < filedata.size()-1; j++)`.

This doesn't guarantee that all inserted elements will have a size of i.

If you replace it with `for (unsigned int j = 0; j < filedata.size()-i+1; j++)`, then j will go up to the last index for a string of length i, which is what you are looking for.